# Bending to Catenoid without twist

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, isometry

Minimum radius $r=c$  central line of a Catenoid

$$ \sqrt{x^2+y^2} =c \cosh  (z/c)$$

is to be mapped by isometrically  bending it to a straight line (black) of length $ 2 \pi c $ *without twist*.

With twist, a catenoid ( right or left handed) results, as is well known and parameterized as

$$ (x,y,z)= (u \cos v, u \sin v, \pm c v); $$

Animations show
$$ \text{ Right or left Helicoid } \to \text{Catenoid} \to \text{ Left or Right  Helicoid } $$

[Catenoid Helicoid Deformation](https://www.geogebra.org/m/dEhwEJvJ)

However, with no twist to the black line another intermediate shape would result. For an idea of the expected symmetrical shape in the neighborhood of central line it could resemble a surface like this, call it a Frill:

[image]

So the animations could show
$$ \text{ Right or left Helicoid } \to \text{Frill} \to \text{Left ot Right  Helicoid } $$

and back again.

What odes or pdes in isometric mapping can define this new shape?